# Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and that $f$ is a linear functional on $W$. Prove $\exists$ $h$ on $V$ such that $h(w)=f(w) \forall w\in W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First of all, from what I can gather there is basically no distinction between linear functional and linear transformation. Then for this question, if there is a linear transformation on a subspace, am I supposed to show that a mapping on a subspace can be extended to the whole space?

Comment: A functional has a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can show that a linear transformation $W\to Y$ can be extended to all of $V$. Given a basis $B = (b_i)_{i\in I}$ for $W$, $B$ can be extended to a basis $B' = (b_i)_{i\in J}$ for $V$, where $J\supseteq I$. Let $U$ be the subspace of all linear combinations of the $\{b_j\mid j\in (J\setminus I)\}$. Then $V = W\oplus U$, and every $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as $v = v_W + v_U$ for unique $v_W \in W, v_U \in U$. Now just define $h(v) = f(v_W)$.